# formula Resource on record Trigger flow in not fetching an any value

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I have created record Triggered flow but the formula resource is not fetching any value.

I have created one formula for 'StartDate' (which is date field on warranty object and I have another field 'Procedure Date'(This is text field on surgery object as I can not mapped it directly I have created a resource formula to mapped with start Date.

here is my formula and flow, I am not able identify the issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to debug warranty record and May I know, what you have received in `Start Date`?

Comment: @Raj - yes, I am getting a null value in the debug. here is my debug log - 
Create one NMD_Warranty__c record where

Active__c = true
End_Date__c = {!WarrantyEndDate} (null)
Patient__c = {!$Record.Patient__r.Id} (a0L8K000002GRGFUA4)
Start_Date__c = {!proDate} (null)
Surgery__c = {!$Record.Id} (a218K000000XoP1QAK)
Result

A record is ready to be created when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.
a9c8K0000008PopQAE

Comment: Please double confirm, you're Surgery object record is having the value for the field "Procedure Date". If it's not.. it's just pass the null value as above.

Comment: yes I checked multiple times Procedure Date does have the value but its still passes the null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the format is an issue on here. Please provide date value in the field `Procedure_Date__c` in Standard Salesforce format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Then Your formula **DATEVALUE('YYYY-MM-DD')** will easily convert that text date into Date which accept in `Start Date` (Date type field).

- Ex: 2024-03-09 -> DATEVALUE('2024-03-09') provide valid date value.

If you're following an Non standard format (other then `YYYY-MM-DD`). Let's say it's `DD-MM-YYYY` format means, Your formula will need to be follows,

```
DATE(VALUE(RIGHT({!$Record.Procedure_Date__c}, 4)),
VALUE(MID({!$Record.Procedure_Date__c},4,2)),
VALUE(LEFT({!$Record.Procedure_Date__c},2))
)
```

- Ex: 09-03-2024 format with above formula provide a valid date value.

So please follow the standard format, or construct a formula as like your available format.

Hope it helps.